# case break causing error while compiling with gcc

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Error while compiling  error: 
break statement not within loop or switch
case label 'not within a switch statement

I couldn't attach the whole code because it's too bug if you insist to see the whole thing let me know and I'll upload it some how.

```
void S9xSetupDefaultKeymap()
{   
    S9xUnmapAllControls();

    // Build key map
    s9xcommand_t cmd;

    // Player 1

    S9xMapButton( 65, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad1 Left"), false );    // A
    S9xMapButton( 68, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad1 Right"), false );   // D
    S9xMapButton( 87, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad1 Up"), false );      // W
    S9xMapButton( 83, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad1 Down"), false );    // S

    S9xMapButton( 79, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad1 X"), false );       // O
    S9xMapButton( 80, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad1 Y"), false );       // P
    S9xMapButton( 75, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad1 A"), false );       // K
    S9xMapButton( 76, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad1 B"), false );       // L

    S9xMapButton( 88, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad1 L"), false );       // X
    S9xMapButton( 77, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad1 R"), false );       // M

    S9xMapButton( 13, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad1 Start"), false );   // Enter
    S9xMapButton( 16, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad1 Select"), false );  // Shift

    // Player 2

    S9xMapButton( 70, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad2 Left"), false );    // F
    S9xMapButton( 72, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad2 Right"), false );   // H
    S9xMapButton( 84, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad2 Up"), false );      // T
    S9xMapButton( 71, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad2 Down"), false );    // G

    S9xMapButton( 67, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad2 X"), false );       // C
    S9xMapButton( 86, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad2 Y"), false );       // V
    S9xMapButton( 66, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad2 A"), false );       // B
    S9xMapButton( 78, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad2 B"), false );       // N

    S9xMapButton( 89, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad2 L"), false );       // Y
    S9xMapButton( 85, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad2 R"), false );       // U

    S9xMapButton( 81, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad2 Start"), false );   // Q
    S9xMapButton( 69, cmd = S9xGetCommandT("Joypad2 Select"), false );  // E


    case "joypad1 down":
    break;

    case "joypad1 x":
    break;

    case "joypad1 y":
    break;

    case "joypad1 a":
    break;

    case "joypad1 b":
    break;

    case "joypad1 l":
    break;

    case "joypad1 r":
    break;

    case "joypad1 start":
    break;

    case "joypad1 select"
    break;

    // player 2

    case "joypad2 left":
    break;

    case "joypad2 right":
    break;

    case "joypad2 up":
    break;

    case "joypad2 down":
    break;

    case "joypad2 x":
    break;

    case "joypad2 y":
    break;

    case "joypad2 a":
    break;

    case "joypad2 b":
    break;

    case "joypad2 l":
    break;

    case "joypad2 r":
    break;

    case "joypad2 start":
    break;

    case "joypad2 select":
    break;
```

Comment: You should trust what your compiler tells you. There's no `switch` statement, `case` with strings won't work as you'd expect. Get a book and learn the basics ...

Comment: Read some basics first. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson5.html or any other tutorial will teach use how to use switch statement.

Comment: If you are not willing to answer don't give me a thumb down.

Comment: I got this in an open source project, I'm not a c++ programmer and the guy who made it had compile it before some how.

Comment: These "case" statements you have provided here are incorrect (missing "switch", also you cannot use strings as case in standard C/C++) and do nothing ("case" immediately followed by "break") so there is no way this program works as it is.

Comment: What are you doing messing around with SNES9x? If you want to make a SNES9x frontend (not entirely sure what you're doing though) may I suggest making a libretro frontend instead? Grab the libretro header from here https://github.com/Themaister/RetroArch/blob/master/libretro.h and link against a number of emulator cores, including SNES9x. www.libretro.org

Answer (score 2):

Example syntax for case

```
switch (variable)
{
   case 1:
      //Do stuff
      break;
   case 2:
      //Do stuff
      break;
   default:
      //Do stuff
      break;
}
```

Remember that by using switch statement you can only proces integer variables. And you need to specify, which variable `case` statements refer to using `switch` statement. If you'll insist on testing a `char*` variable, the behaviour will be different than what you expect, as you'll be comparing just pointers, not content of the `char*` array.

In your case, you'll be better of using `if`, `else if`.